# Angular bind html to div without using iframe

Tags: html, angular

I have an angular app. Now I have a link like https://example.com/Exam/denemedir.html . I want to bind this html to div element without using iframe, because I want to effect css code in page.css in angular app. With Iframe css codes doesn't work

This is my html code

```
<ion-content>
      <div class="text-center head">
        <a routerLink="/subjects"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
        <h5>{{subject.name}}</h5>
        <a class="home" routerLink="/home"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-home"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="content"[innerHTML]="content | safe : 'html'" ></div>
 </ion-content>
```

this is my safe pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml, SafeStyle, SafeScript, SafeUrl, SafeResourceUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
  name: 'safe'
})
export class SafePipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(protected sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
 
 public transform(value: any, type: string): SafeHtml | SafeStyle | SafeScript | SafeUrl | SafeResourceUrl {
    switch (type) {
            case 'html': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
            case 'style': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(value);
            case 'script': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(value);
            case 'url': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(value);
            case 'resourceUrl': return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(value);
            default: throw new Error(`Invalid safe type specified: ${type}`);
        }
  }

}
```

but I don't know how to bind this url html to div element. Is there any way to bind html from url ?

Comment: can you elaborate on CSS part more ? what exactly you want ?

Comment: I have one panel In panel I create html for mobile app. I create html file in panel. In mobile app I want embed this html.  Both part have same css codes. so I want to bind this html code to mobile app. I want to use database as a last choice. If possible I want to save as html in panel part and store just html name inside database rather that whole html string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe this is what you need:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56969578/5576972

which gives something like:

**HTML:**

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtml"></div>
```

**ts:**

```
  myHtml:SafeHtml="";
  constructor(
      private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
  ) {
  }

  async updateHtml(){
let newHtml = await this.httpClient.get(url, {responseType: "text"}).toPromise();

    this.myHtml =  this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(newHtml);
  }
```